# g++ option E to join local header files only

Tags: makefile, g++, compiler-options

the following option

```
g++ main.cpp -E
```

will join all headers and renders macros. It does generate over 10MB output for me. I just need to render includes and not macros. And also I need to limit rendering includes to local files

```
#include "headerfile.hpp"
```

I do not want to render

```
#include <iostream>
```

I dont want such horrible code:

```
namespace std __attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default")))
{

# 60 "/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream" 3
  extern istream cin;
  extern ostream cout;
  extern ostream cerr;
  extern ostream clog;


  extern wistream wcin;
  extern wostream wcout;
  extern wostream wcerr;
  extern wostream wclog;
```

Is there any way to limit option E to what I need?

Comment: Preprococess or do not preprocess - there is no half-way house.

Comment: @PaulR I just want to merge a library. is there any better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge a library" ?

Comment: i want my `main.cpp`, `header1.cpp`,  `folder1/header2.cpp`, ... `folder10/header78.cpp` which are all included in `main.cpp` (or included from each other) to be merged into one file called `joined.cpp` . So when I compile the single file `joined.cpp` I get the same results.

Comment: OK - just use `cat` then.

Comment: @PaulR cat does not consider which file includes which and it does not consider the order of files. maybe `header1.hpp` calls `header63.hpp` so  `header63.hpp` must be placed before `header1.hpp`. cat cannot handle it.

Comment: OK I would suggest `m4` then - it understands #includes and won't expand macros - you would still need to filter out system #includes though, perhaps using something like 'sed` to filter the source first.

Comment: @PaulR `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m4’` how should I use it?

Comment: No, `m4` is a preprocessor, not a command line option. It should be in /usr/bin on pretty much any *nix installation.